# Filter Geocoder by Country

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, filter, geocoding

I'm trying to filter esri's geocoder for a specific country.  I've had some success, but nothing works extremely well.  I would have thought simply adding sourceCountry = "xxx" to the parameters of the arcgisGeocoder would work, but I couldn't get it to zoom correctly.   here are the three versions I've found:

1. attach a condition to the URL
2. go with no filter
3. use suffix = ", USA"

I'm attaching a code snippet as well below of these.

I'm wondering: Has anyone found a better way to filter the autocomplete options and have the map zoom to the correct coordinates?

```
//1. this one works okay, but the autofill is much slower than the others

   var myGeocoders = [{
      url: "http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer?sourceCountry=USA",
      name: "EsriWorldLocator",
      placeholder: "Find a place",
      autoComplete: true,
     singleLineFieldName: "SingleLine"
}];


var geocoder = new Geocoder ({
    map: map,
    arcgisGeocoder: false,
    geocoders: myGeocoders
    }, dom.byId("search")
    );
geocoder.autoComplete = true;


//2. This is the original, no filter

var geocoder =  new Geocoder({
  arcgisGeocoder: {

    placeholder: "Find a place"
  },
  autoComplete: true,
  map: map
}, dom.byId("search")
);   



//3.  This one has a great autocomplete, but it zooms to a seemingly random location

var geocoder =  new Geocoder({
  arcgisGeocoder: {
    //sourceCountry: "USA",
    suffix: ", USA",
    placeholder: "Find a place"
  },
  autoComplete: true,
  autoNavigate: true,
  map: map
}, dom.byId("search")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the searchExtent AND sourceCountry based on the country-code from here (https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocode-coverage.htm)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Here's a dialogue on GeoNet on this subject https://geonet.esri.com/thread/119441